# Find two least composite numbers $n$ such that $n\mid2^n-2$ and $n\mid3^n-3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $n\mid2^n-2$
>   $n\mid3^n-3$.

It comes down to

> $2^n \equiv 2 \mod n$
>     $3^n \equiv 3 \mod n$

But how can I solve this?

Comment: The [carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) should do the job, though perhaps not minimally.  If you really need the least two $n$, I'd just search.

Comment: Could you tell us the source of this question?

Comment: @junkquill It's from "250 Problems in Elementary Number Theory", №27 Here is the link: http://www.isinj.com/mt-aime/250%20Problems%20in%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Sierpinski%20(1970).pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, one clear path for the solution is to consider [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number). The first two work: $561= 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17$ and $1105= 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$.

The solutions $n \le 10000$ are
$$
\begin{align}
561&= 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \\
1105&= 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \\
1729&= 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \\
2465&= 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 29 \\
2701&= 37 \cdot 73 \\
2821&= 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 31 \\
6601&= 7 \cdot 23 \cdot 41 \\
8911&= 7 \cdot 19 \cdot 67 \\
\end{align}
$$
Of these, $2701$ is *not* a Carmichael number.